# Cutting sprite sheets into individual bitmaps dynamically with variable frame size

Tags: java, android, animation, sprite

I want to create a cookie-cutter-type class that takes a source rectangle and dynamically steps through each frame in a sprite sheet until each image has been cut out for animations. I can do this no problem when each frame size is identical in the sprite sheet, but it is near impossible to find sprite sheets with any complexity in the animations that has identical frame sizes. For example:

[image: Simple sprite sheet with constant frame size]

gets cut and animated just like I want it to, but:

[image: More complex bitmap with variable frame size]

with it's variable frame sizes, gets cut funny (since my program currently assumes all frames are the same size). Is there any way to, in a way, sense frame size for each individual frame in the sprite sheet or is this a lost cause?

Current code to create "cookie cutter" source frame:

```
// Indirect Variable Sets (Sprite Animation and Sprite Sheet Cuts)
    framesPerRow = frameCount/spriteSheetRows;
    spriteWidth = bmp.getWidth() / framesPerRow;    // cut the sheet into pieces based on 
                                                    // sprite width: frames/row ratio
    spriteHeight = bmp.getHeight()/spriteSheetRows; // cut the sheet horizontally into pieces based on
                                                    // total height : total rows ratio

    setSourceRect(new Rect(0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight));
    setFramePeriod(1000 / fps);                     // set the framePeriod based on desired fps
```

Which is then utilized in my update method:

```
public void update(long gameTimeInMillis){
    // If the game time has been longer than the frame period...
    // the reason that we need frameTicker is so that we can use our variable (frameTicker)
    // to keep track of the last time that the frame was updated (relative to our game)
    if (gameTimeInMillis > frameTicker + framePeriod){
        frameTicker = gameTimeInMillis;             // set last update time (current time)
        // increment the animation frame
        currentFrame++;

        // Get current column in sprite sheet:
        // this works like this, imagine we are at frame 20, and we have 5 frames per row
        // 20%5 = 0 so we are at the end of the row, if we are at frame 22, 22%5 = 2, etc.
        frameColumn = currentFrame%framesPerRow;

        // if we are at our max frame count (note, we start at 0) then reset our animation
        if(currentFrame >= frameCount){ 
            currentFrame = 0;                   
        }

        // increment the sprite sheet row if we are at the end of the row
        if(frameColumn == 0){
            currentRow++;
        }

        // if we are at our max rows (note, we start at 0) then reset our animation rows
        if(currentRow >= spriteSheetRows){
            currentRow = 0;
        }

        // define the "cookie cutter" sourceRectangle for our sprite sheet
        this.sourceRect.left = frameColumn * spriteWidth;
        this.sourceRect.right = this.sourceRect.left + spriteWidth;
        this.sourceRect.top = currentRow * spriteHeight;
        this.sourceRect.bottom = this.sourceRect.top + spriteHeight;
        Log.d(TAG, "Top coordinates = " + currentRow);
    }
}
```

My goal, since I am no artist, is to work with pre-rendered sprite sheets so that I can work on my skills in a 2D animated environment. The problem is, most sprite sheets that I find seem to have variable frames, making them fairly useless for me unless I can figure out a way to cut them more precisely (or another means of cutting, is there an API tool I am missing?)

Answer (score 0):

You could add some metadata to go along with the sprite sheet that defines the pixel positions plus width/height of each frame in the sheet. It is more work than having a perfect grid, but it will enable you to use a wider variety of sprite sheets as-is. For example (not to scale) if you go to fetch frame 1, you would find that it is 16x32 starting at pixel position 128, and you can calculate the texture coordinates based on the width/height of the whole sheet. It sounds messy, but once you get it working, it should give you more flexibility, and be reusable across a variety of sprite sheets.

Otherwise, you could cut and paste individual frames onto a grid using Gimp. Or, cut the frames into individual images, all with the same width/height, and assemble the individual images into a sprite sheet using something like ImageMagick. I don't remember the actual commands, but I used ImageMagick from the command-line to assemble some of Reiner's Tilesets into sprite sheets. ImageMagick will concatenate all the images in a directory, and you can even tell it to resize them for you so you can start with higher res images and force them into powers of two if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sprites as an array of `Rect`s. (Seriously, you do not want to store them in a 2D array.)

```
Rect[] frames = new Rect[TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES];
```

Now, the computer has no way of knowing how to cut your sheet. The easiest way might be to have a text file that looks like:

```
x,y,width,height
x,y,width,height
x,y,width,height
```

This will allow you to use weird spritesheets that have varying widths and heights. It also means that you can have bits of the image that are in no sprite (such as for when there are borders around each frame or frames you don't want to use). Use file IO to put them into the array. (Note you may want to set BitMapFactory Options to not scale your bitmap).

You can draw the nth frame with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, frames[n],
    new RectF(x, y, x + frames[n].width(), y + frames[n].height()),
    paint);
```